# Microsoft Excel vlookup problems

Tags: excel, vlookup

can we use vlookup to find text values, and what are the steps if possible.

`=vlookup(the lookup_value, tablearray, column_num, logic), text value`.

I want to look for the country with the a certain population, and using the population has the lookup value.

Comment: Excel has some examples of the use. What have you tried and what errors did you get? Show your work and we can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in a new sheet:

| Nation | Population |  | Search | Closest match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 100 |  | 3 | =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(IF(D2-AGGREGATE(14,6,B2:B10/(B2:B10<=D2),1)<AGGREGATE(15,6,B2:B10/(B2:B10>=D2),1)-D2,AGGREGATE(14,6,B2:B10/(B2:B10<=D2),1),AGGREGATE(15,6,B2:B10/(B2:B10>=D2),1)),B:B,0)) |
| b | 10 |  |  |  |
| c | 7 |  |  |  |
| d | 6 |  |  |  |
| e | 5 |  |  |  |
| f | 4 |  |  |  |
| g | 1 |  |  |  |
| h | 33 |  |  |  |
| i | 0 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup value is the population, you may want a non-exact search since this may be up or down from what you're searching. The key thing to know about the VLOOKUP is the population HAS to be the leftmost part of the table you're searching, and the column # component is how many columns to the right of that key you want to pull the name from. So if it was a table Column A population, B as the country name you would use 2 for the column, since it's the second over.

However, an XLOOKUP may be better suited for what you're doing. It allows you define the search column and the column you want the results to pull from and doesn't constrain itself by the positioning of these as long as they are the same height (height being how many rows down it goes, these ranges must match). additionally, the search for nonexact gives you more options than a vlookup, such as being able to take the previous lowest option or the next highest. and so on.

If your table is Column A Population, Column B country names, and let's say D1 is the population you're searching for this is what the formulae would look like:

`=xlookup(D1, A:A, B:B,0,1)` (for the exact or next highest match, make sure to lock cells for what works for your specific case)